# Wants to achieve parallelism/concurrency to read files

Tags: java, concurrency

Hi I am stuck in a scenario where I have to hit a database on the basis of Id to fetch a file names. 
Once when I get a file name I need to read that file and set its data into a variable of a bean class.

I am creating a GET API where I am getting Class A along with B & C. For class C (having two variables name as int cId & 
String data) I have to read a files from a specified location but for this first I have to fetch all the file names from the database
on the basis of cId then I have to read it & set its data into the data field of class C.

Here I am having 3 bean classes (A,B & C) with one-to-many relationship. Class A is having one-to-many relationship with class B
and class B is having one-to-many relationship with class C.
below is the structure of my bean classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@DynamicUpdate
class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "a_id")
    private long aId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy
    private Set<B> bList = new LinkedHashSet<B>();

    //---Getter/Setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
Class B{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "b_id")
    private long BId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dashboardSection", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy
    private Set<C> cList = new LinkedHashSet<C>();

    //---Getter/Setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
Class C{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long cId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;

    @Transient
    private String data;

    //---Getter/Setter
}
```

Logic that I have applied to read files But I need to achieve it through parallelism/concurrency how may I? please help:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bList.size(); i++) {
                            B b = bList.get(i);
                            List<C> cList = new ArrayList<C>(b.getLinkedViewList());
                            int cSize = cList.size();

                            for (int j = 0; j < cSize; j++) {
                                C c = cList.get(j);

                                int CId = Integer.parseInt(c.getCId());


                                outputfile = customQuery.fetchTableInfo(CId);

                                if ((outputfile != null) && (!outputfile.equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
                                    String fileName = outputfile.substring(outputfile.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,outputfile.length());// seprating File Name
                                    if ((session != null)&&(channel.isConnected())) {
                                        String fileToJson = readFiles.readFileForDashboard(sftpChannel,fileName);// Reading Files
                                        c.setData(fileToJson);
                                    } else {
                                        c.setData("Session is null OR SFTP Channel is not Connected, to read file");
                                        response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                                                .body("Connection Could not establish to read file!");
                                        log.info(
                                                "Connection Could not establish to read file!/ session object is null");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                                            .body("No file present in a table");
                                }
                            }

                        }
```

Read file Logic:

```
public String readFileForDashboard(ChannelSftp sftpChannel, String fileName) {

        String response;
        try {

            String src = fileName;

            InputStream in = sftpChannel.get(src);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder inputData = new StringBuilder("");
            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                inputData.append(line).append("\n");

            JSONArray array = null;

            if (fileName.toLowerCase().contains("csv")) {
                array = CDL.toJSONArray(inputData.toString());

            } else if (fileName.toLowerCase().contains("xls")) {
                ...........

            }  else {

            }
            response = array.toString();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            response = "File Not Found";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            .........

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ..........

        } finally {
            ...........

        }
        return response;

    }
```